# Are there protocols which utilize TCP shutdown for writing (a.k.a half-close, SHUT_WR)?

Tags: tcp, transport-protocol

In TCP socket programming, there is a feature that allows to shutdown socket only one way, where data cannot be read from the socket, but it can still be written to. I've seen it referred as "shutdown for writing", or less commonly, "half-close". In this mode, a peer issues `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`. The other side receives 0 bytes when doing `read()`, but it can still succesfully write to the socket and the other peer can read from it.

Now, I am trying to implement a SOCKS proxy server and I wonder if there exists an actual real-life protocol that utilizes this "half-close". From what I see, most implementations of proxy servers just `close()` both sides of the tunnel once `read()`ing 0 bytes from either of the sides. Everything seemingly works when doing it that way.

Are there actual real-life uses of this option or can I safely ignore it when implementing my proxy server?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about programming and host/server implementations of a protocol are off-topic here. You can ask about programming on [su], where there are many network-savvy programmers.

Comment: A simple search for [applications using TCP half-close](https://www.google.com/search?q=applications+using+TCP+half-close) will provide hints, that there are actually [applications doing this](https://www.excentis.com/blog/tcp-half-close-a-cool-feature-that-is-now-broken/) and [how some firewalls deal with it](https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000ClI4CAK) (and break the application).

Comment: Good old HTTP is one - if used with a very basic client or server